# How to suppress error message "Server Unreachable. Please check your network/configuration settings"?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have recently started using a Windows-10 virtual machine (VMWare 6.0.7) and it is behaving satisfactorily in all respects (so far as I can tell) including access to network shared drives and the Internet.

But a message appears in the lower-left corner every fifteen seconds or so:-

```
Resolving Web Filtering Credentials - please wait
```

followed immediately by

```
Server Unreachable. Please check your network/configuration settings
```

The messages are appearing on a little black stripe the same as one gets when email arrives, and accompanied by a blue-green blob icon.

This is getting rather annoying. Clicking the messages, even on the X in the upper right corner, doesn't prevent them from appearing or start up any useful application.

Does anyone know what is causing these messages and how to get rid of them?

**Edit** the error message in glorious technicolour:-

[image: the error message in glorious technicolour]

I noticed the little green icon in the task bar, but clicking it causes it to vanish.

Comment: Just wondering - would you be able to screenshot the window? I cant see what is calling it while doing a quick google search. In Windows 10 you can specify in the settings app what applications can alert you, the program might show up their if it isnt windows

Comment: @Lister, thank you for your suggestion; I will look into the settings app, and get a screen print as soon as possible, which probably won't be until Monday.

Comment: @Lister, managed to get a screen shot.

Comment: I don't recognise the icon, does it appear in task manager while its down in your taskbar?

Comment: @Lister, the task manager claims there are no applications running, but there are two background processes with the icon, calling themselves "Desktop Web Proxy Application", whatever that is. I'll see if I can turn something up on this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I could not find out anything about "Desktop Web Proxy Application". Uninstalling it has if not exactly fixed the problem at least got rid of it.

Comment: No worries, I would be wary of that VM if you didn't install that software or know of anything that would have done it. Benefits of a VM ofcourse you can blow it out the water and start again if you want to be safe.